# homebrew jenkins does not save configurations

Tags: jenkins

I am using jenkins installed from homebrew.
However every time I set javax.jmdns = off in [jenkins log level page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ko8N.png) it disappeared after restart.

Anyway to make it permanent?

Thx for any advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `Logger.getLogger("javax.jmdns").setLevel(Level.OFF)` in `.jenkins/init.groovy.d/logging.groovy`

#### Full file .jenkins/init.groovy.d/logging.groovy

```
import java.util.logging.Level
import java.util.logging.Logger

Logger.getLogger("javax.jmdns").setLevel(Level.OFF)
```